# jQuery hotkeys plugin

Tags: javascript, forms

I've found a [nice plugin to bind hotkey combinations](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about) like Ctrl+A for submit buttons, but I don't understand how I can apply this to my form submit button.

Can anyone put me on the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you'll want to do is add it in a separate js file in a module. Use `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`and identify the form that you want the script run on. Then In `hook_form_alter()` use `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js');` to add the JavaScript file to that page.

Also in `hook_form_alter()`, you'll want to identify the button you want to add this to and add a prefix and suffix markup to it.

```
$form['button']['#prefix'] = array('<div class="my-button-class">');
$form['button']['#suffix'] = array('</div>');
```

In the JavaScript file, where you see div.foo you'll want to enter the name of that div that you created on the button.

```
$('div.my-button-class').unbind('keydown', 'Ctrl+a', fn);
```

Also in hook_form_alter() you need to add a class to an input or button or whatever you are using.

```
$form['field']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('my-other-class'));
```

For this, in the js file you need to replace:

```
$('input.my-other-class').bind('keyup', '$', function(){
```

EDIT: Note the *input*.class. If you're targeting a different type of element this will need to be changed accordingly. Same with *div*. class. I think you can also do IDs like input#my-input-id.